# Static variables generating problems with C# (Windows 8)

Tags: c#, variables, asynchronous, static, manualresetevent

I am not a used C# programmer, so if this is stupid, sorry :-)

I am developing a C# app for Windows 8. I need to do a web request, and therefore, I have a callback to handle the request data.

I am using the standard approach:

```
private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private static void daCallback(IAsyncResult data) {
   ...
   SampleDataSource.allDone.Set();
}

// This is the Class CONSTRUCTOR
public SampleDataSource() {
   # before anything, reset allDone:

  string request = "http://some.url.com";
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(request) as HttpWebRequest;
  webRequest.Method = "POST";

  webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(daCallback), webRequest);

  Debug.WriteLine("Asked to begin get response");

  SampleDataSource.allDone.WaitOne(12000);

  Debug.WriteLine("Done Waiting");
   #...
}
```

When running, allDone (inside do_something) is not initialized. I even added a condition around to compare allDone with null, and yep, it is null.

The "Done Waiting" message never gets print at all...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need a reset event at all? (And are you sure some other code somewhere isn't setting it to null? From the code you've posted here it shouldn't be...)

Comment: what are you supposed to be doing in the first place

Comment: @Cameron, it doesn't matter if I am calling Reset, or set, or WaitOne. It is not defined. Why?

Comment: @ambs perhaps you have some other variable/property etc. named allDone ?

Comment: Only these references to allDone is this namespace/class.

Comment: @ambs then just reference it via `YourClassName.allDone` and see what happens...

Comment: @Yahia, tried it. I still get complains about NullReferenceException.  Something weird here :-)

Comment: @ambs that contradicts what you showed as code... it is either a weird compiler/runtime issue OR some other (beside what you show) does something to produce this behaviour... I bet on the latter...

Comment: @Yahia, added some more code in the post, hopefully that can show some stupid error I am doing :-)

Comment: Can it be because I am doing this in a constructor? :-|

Comment: Fond out that WaitOne should receive a number of milliseconds for Windows 8 Store Apps... but still no fun.

Comment: Can't understand why, but initializing allDone in the method works (now that WaitOne has a timeout). But still, can't understand why it doesn't work as above.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a static field from an instance method. Use `YourClassName.allDone.Reset()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the classname in front of your call to `allDone`, because it's static.
So instead of

```
allDone.Reset();
```

try

```
//replace CLASS with whatever you named your class
CLASS.allDone.Reset();
```

Equivalent approach to all other calls.

Comment: That would explain it all. But it seems it continues to be with a null value.

Comment: @ambs Did you try setting a breakpoint at `private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);`? This way you can be sure it really gets called or not (and that allDone isn't null afterwards).